# How do I save the ICC profile with pillow and LZW compression

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, compression, python-imaging-library

## The issue

When trying to save an image with an icc_profile the profile isnt saving with the rest of the image. the tiff info is copying across correctly but when I open the image again it has no icc_profile in the image info

```
pilImage.save(savePath, "Tiff", compression = 'tiff_lzw', tiffinfo = { 282: 300, 283: 300 ,296: 2}, icc_profile = oldtags.info.get('icc_profile'))
```

I am able to print out oldtags.info.get('icc_profile') and that is present in the image

I am using python 3.7.4 and the latest pillow version.

How do I save the colour profile?